# use WooCommerce classes in own php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to create a woocommerce page, where headers can be set manually and no design/theme will be called?

My approach was to just create a php file in the wp-content/uploads folder, but how to access classes like WC_Order in there?
Other approach would be to just create a new page in wordpress and use a shortcode, but then my theme will be loaded, which I don't want.

Comment: I don't understand you are asking (perhaps you could edit your question to elaborate and make it clearer), but I think maybe the [REST API](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/) would be relevant to your interests if you are trying to get order data without loading your theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After activate woo commerce plugin use global variable

```
global $woocommerce;
```

by which you can access woo commerce for those pages where headers can be set manually and no design/theme will be called.

Check out below link for add custom pages:
[Create a Custom Page](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give me more information on how ti achieve that? How do I activate the woocommerce plugin in a blank php file?

Comment: plugin need to activate in word press environment from admin section and after then in your word press you can use it in blank php file.

Comment: woocommerce is activated. Where do I have to put the php file, that wordpress loads it with woocommerce instead of just loading the php file alone via the webserver?

Comment: check out link for create custom. page.http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: That was a great link. Now it works for me. Would you like to sum this up in an answer that i can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want create blank template page without theme styles replace `get_header();` with

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title"
          content="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?> - <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php wp_head(); ?> <!-- Important! - Must be -->
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If wp_head() is important, then it's not a solution for me. I need to send own headers because it's a dynamically generated file download.

Comment: :) You can remove it - it is tagged from my other project (sorry) but your custom template will be without any styles.